# Same Oracle Database Same SQL different sql plans

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am facing this issue which I couldnt understand. I am firing the same SQL in Same Oracle Database. First directly in the sqlplus session and then using a reporting tool(Inet). The same sql uses different execution plans. One is taking 2 mins to execute and other is taking 30 mins.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe bind variable peeking or different session configuration. Please post your query. You could also check "Database Resource Manager", maybe reporting tool is capped. There are too many possible scenarios, so please be more specific about your case.

Comment: Its a simple group by select query without any bind variables. The other reports are working fine.

Comment: Check if you have more than one row in v$sql/gv$sql view for the same (or nearly the same) query. If yes, check if they have different sql_ids. If yes, compare execution plans for these two sql_ids using dbms_xplan package.

Comment: Does the BI tool "wrap" the query inside another query to provide for filters that the user can tinker with - that can add quite an overhead.